# Database Primary Key is incrementing, but no new rows are being added

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing my first python script, and I am trying to connect it to a mysql db to insert rows.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","xxx","pytest" )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `first_table` (`name`) VALUES ('boop') ")
```

When I check the mysql db via phpmyadmin, it contains no rows, however if the auto incrementing ID was 5 and then I run the script 2 times, when I insert a new row it inserts it as id= 8 so the script has been incrementing the primary key but not inserting the rows?

The script reports no mysql errors, so I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: you forgot to call commit, call `db.commit()` after insert query

Comment: ah ok...I am used to working with PHP, why is a commit required? what does it do?

Comment: [`MySQLConnection.commit()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_MySQLConnection_commit.html)

Comment: @Melbourne2991, a commit "saves" the state of the database. That is to say that it writes all pending transactions.

Comment: Hm, in what situations may that be needed out of curiosity? Why would one want their transactions pending @johnthexiii

Comment: @Melbourne2991 for DB changes, insert, update, delete .. you need commit , Whereas select, join don't need commit

Comment: You'd want your transactions pending, in case a screw up is made, then you can rollback.

Comment: There are times when an auto increment primary key is incremented for a new record but then the insert fails. Result is the key is still incremented but no record is inserted.

Comment: You also might want to change your password now that it's public...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yuor case please use

```
import MySQLdb

    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","jimmypq79","pytest" )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `first_table` (`name`) VALUES ('boop') ")
    db.commit()
```

Please put this in top of the code like this--

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","jimmypq79","pytest" )
db.autocommit(True)
```

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059424/about-mysqldb-conn-autocommittrue)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 cursor.autocommit(True)
```

in the beginning of the code for automatically committing the changes .

Comment: The cursor has no attribute 'autocommit', but the connection has.

Answer (score 1):

you use,

```
  db.commit()
```

after insert query