# Python, MySQL: Getting Null Inserts, but print() is giving value, and SQL is valid?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

In the following code:

```
print(str(processedEmails))
print(campaignId)
```

returns values I was expecting.

What I'm trying to do (why I ran print() statements to check):

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE campaigns SET campaign_finish_date = (NOW()) AND queue_size =' + str(processedEmails) + ' WHERE id=' + campaignId)
```

checking via phpMyAdmin:

```
NOW() = 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
campaignId = 0 (what I set as default)
```

Values not transferred.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQLdb module, you need to commit() the query if autocommit() is False (default).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059424/about-mysqldb-conn-autocommittrue).

Edit #1:

Then grant that the query is being successfully executed. Have you tried to execute that query via phpMyAdmin? Does it work as expected?

I've noticed that you've a AND instead a comma (',') on your update query:

You've this:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE campaigns SET campaign_finish_date = (NOW()) AND queue_size =' + str(processedEmails) + ' WHERE id=' + campaignId)
```

Instead of this:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE campaigns SET campaign_finish_date = (NOW()), queue_size =' + str(processedEmails) + ' WHERE id=' + campaignId)
```

Comment: Yea--ran into that problem early on, but I have the commit() in my code.  Will edit my post to show [but yea...def issue among many people]

Comment: that fixed it.  heh... syntax :\ ..thank you so much!